# EJS - Include config from JSON File

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ejs

How do load a value from the `.json` file to the `.ejs` file.

Example file `.json`

```
{
    "value": "value2"
}
```

How to load a value of `value2` from the `value` column?

Example output (HTML rendered by EJS)

```html
Yes, that's "value2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//read the json file
const values = require("./pathtojson/file.json");
```

`app.locals` can be used to expose variables to (EJS) templates for e.g.:

```
// app.js
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = app.listen(3000);

//using app.locals
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  app.locals.values = 1;
  res.render('index.ejs');
});

//another way of passing variables is:
app.get('/anotherway', function(req, res) {
    res.render('testPage', { jsonValue: values });
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to put a value from a JSON file to a script on the page. I want my google tracking ID to be read from the JSON file (This would make the work easier etc.)

Comment: It would be much better if you use .env file for this use case. .env files are very useful for setting up the environmnet/configuration for your application and you can use the dotenv library to parse the .env file and get the configuration data like in your case the google tracking ID. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem.

Comment: I know I can use the `.env` file. Using it here is a pretty good idea. I just don't know how to do it. I'm thinking of a solution like the usual node.js - `process.env.SECRET`

Comment: You're thinking in the right direction. For more info and examples on dotenv follow this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv   and go to the usage section.

Comment: I know, I've been using this library for a long time.